# Percentage calculation from pivot table pandas

Tags: pandas, pivot-table, python-3.6, percentage

I have a set of data which I have already imported from excel xlsx file. After that I determine to find out the percentage of the total profit from each of the customer segment. I manage to use the pivot_table to summarize the the total profit of each customer segment. However, I also would like to know the percentage. How do I do that?

**Pivot_table**

```
 profit = df.pivot_table(index = ['Customer Segment'], values = ['Profit'], aggfunc=sum)
```

**Result** So far

```
Customer Segment      Profit
    A                    a
    B                    b
    C                    c
    D                    d
```

Maybe adding the percentage column to the pivot table would be an ideal way. But how can I do that?

Comment: percentage of the total profit, so a/(a+b+c+d), ...? If so probably easiest to do it afterwards.

Comment: yes, I know the formula. But from the profits that I categorized in the pivot table, how do I make use of it?

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
df['percent'] = df['Profit']/sum(df['Profit'])
```

Answer (score 0):

For example you have this data frame:

```
    Customer Segment    Customer    Profit
0         A                AAA        12
1         B                BBB        43
2         C                CCC        45
3         D                DDD        23
4         D                EEE        67
5         C                FFF        21
6         B                GGG        45
7         A                JJJ        67
8         A                KKK        32
9         B                LLL        13
10        C                MMM        43
11        D                NNN        13
```

From the above data frame you want to make pivot table.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

tableframe = pd.pivot_table(df, values='Profit', index=['Customer Segment'], aggfunc=np.sum)
```

Here is your pivot table:

```
                  Profit
Customer Segment    
     A              111
     B              101
     C              109
     D              103
```

Now you want to add another column to **tableframe** then compute the percentage.

```
tableframe['percentage'] = ((tableframe.Profit / tableframe.Profit.sum()) * 100)
```

Here is your final **tableframe**:

```
                   Profit   percentage
Customer Segment        
         A          111     26.179245
         B          101     23.820755
         C          109     25.707547
         D          103     24.292453
```